# how to draw a polygon in google map API using array of coordinates?

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps-api-3, polygon, geospatial

I am new to JavaScript and I am trying to use google map API to draw a polygon.  The default paths in the google.maps.Polygons function accept JSON with the following format:

```
 var trianglecoords=[
           {lat: 18.466, lng: -66.518},
           {lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118},
           {lat: 18.166, lng: -66.118},
                 ];
```

however my format is:

```
var trianglecoords=[
                   [18.466,-66.518],
                   [18.466,-66.118],
                   [18.166,-66.118],
                         ];
```

using my format I cannot see the triangle in the map. can anyone help me?

here is my code:

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 5,
    center: {lat: 24.886, lng: -70.268},
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  });

  // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path.
  var triangleCoords = [
    [25.774, -80.190],
    [18.466, -66.118],
    [32.321,-64.757],
    [25.774, -80.190]
  ];

  // Construct the polygon.
  var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: triangleCoords,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
  bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
}
```

Comment: Your format won't work. You need to translate it into either an array of google.maps.LatLng objects or google.maps.LatLngLiteral objects.

Comment: Thank you! it worked when I add the following codes to create latlng objects: 

var points=[];
  for(var i=0;i<4;i++)
  {
  points.push(new google.maps.LatLng(triangleCoords[i][0],triangleCoords[i][1]))
  }

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your format won't work. You need to translate it into either an array of [`google.maps.LatLng`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) objects or [`google.maps.LatLngLiteral`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngLiteral) objects.

Either:

```
var points=[]; 
for(var i=0; i<triangleCoords.length; i++) { 
  points.push(new google.maps.LatLng(triangleCoords[i][0],
                                     triangleCoords[i][1]));
}
// Construct the polygon.
var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
  paths: points,
  strokeColor: '#FF0000',
  strokeOpacity: 0.8,
  strokeWeight: 2,
  fillColor: '#FF0000',
  fillOpacity: 0.35
});
bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
```

Or:

```
var points=[]; 
for(var i=0; i<triangleCoords.length; i++) { 
  points.push({
    lat: triangleCoords[i][0],
    lng: triangleCoords[i][1]
  });
}
// Construct the polygon.
var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
  paths: points,
  strokeColor: '#FF0000',
  strokeOpacity: 0.8,
  strokeWeight: 2,
  fillColor: '#FF0000',
  fillOpacity: 0.35
});
bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
```

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 5,
    center: {
      lat: 24.886,
      lng: -70.268
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  });

  // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path.
  var triangleCoords = [
    [25.774, -80.190],
    [18.466, -66.118],
    [32.321, -64.757],
    [25.774, -80.190]
  ];
  var points = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < triangleCoords.length; i++) {
    points.push({
      lat: triangleCoords[i][0],
      lng: triangleCoords[i][1]
    });
  }
  // Construct the polygon.
  var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: points,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
  bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```